# angular.min.js:63 ReferenceError

Tags: javascript, angularjs, express, mean-stack

Am getting following error when use a factory into angular module

i have factory module like below

```
   angular.module('pollServices', ['ngResource']).factory('Poll', function($resource) {
        return $resource('polls/:pollId', {}, {
          query: { method: 'GET', params: { pollId: 'polls' }, isArray: true }
        })
      });
```

I have another module called `polls` in the same file, i need to use the factory module to this app so i have called it in module config like

```
angular.module('polls', ['pollServices'])
```

When i call the factory inside this module like

```
 function PollListCtrl($scope) {
             $scope.polls = Poll.query();
}
```

am getting error like

```
angular.min.js:63 ReferenceError: Poll is not defined
    at new PollListCtrl (app.js:29)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you didn't call the `Poll` factory from `PollListCtrl`

```
function PollListCtrl(Poll,$scope) {
         $scope.polls = Poll.query();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to inject pollServices to the controller.

```
angular.module('polls', ['pollServices'])
    .controller('PollListCtrl', PollListCtrl)

PollListCtrl.$inject = ["$scope", "pollServices"];

function PollListCtrl($scope, Poll) {
    $scope.polls = Poll.query();
}
```

Comment: It should be 
PollListCtrl.$inject = ["$scope", "Poll"];